# Mix rgb node logic

Tags: node-editor

I have difficulties in understanding the logic of mix rgb node option “add”, “multiply”, and      “Mix” under conditions of “fac” 0 and 1. Would someone explain with tables and examples. Thank you

Comment: Is the documentation not clear enough? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/color/mix.html#examples

Comment: This [list of Gimp blend modes](https://docs.gimp.org/en/gimp-concepts-layer-modes.html) may be helpful

Answer (score 1):

The Add, Mix, Multiply node options are blending modes, like in Photoshop. You have to play with them to get an idea, there are too many to list now.

the Fac is which side of the mix is stronger, so a value of 0.0 would only show you color 1 in the mix node. A value of 1 would only show the other color. Things get interesting when you have a noise or voronoi in just black and white in the fac input. This drives variation in the material and shows both materials based on a black and white mask. (0-1)